# Поместить дату в текстовое поле

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как загнать дату из `DateTimepicker` в текстовое поле?

Answer (score 2):

Учитесь искать в msdn и гуглить.

Вот тут ответ: [MSDN: DateTimePicker::Value - свойство](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx#Y400)

```
String^ Value;
Value=this->dateTimePicker1->Value.ToString();
textBox0->Text = Value;
```

Для выделения из dateTimePicker1->Value только даты или каких-либо компонент, вот материал: [MSDN: DateTime - структура](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.aspx)

 А вот пример:

```
textBox0->Text = dateTimePicker1->Value.Date.ToString();
```

Comment: убрать время надо! оставить только дату ? и как проголосовать за твой ответ?

Comment: добавлено в ответ. По работе ХэшКод - http://hashcode.ru/faq/ - тут довольно кратко и подробно.